# How to handle bookmarks in Reflowable books

Tags: dynamic-ui, books

I am in the team who builds an eReader which supports Reflowable books and books are in ePub format.
When I launch the Reflowable book the page count is dynamic in nature.

For Example:
Given I have book that has 100 pages on default 100% screen size
When I zoom in to 200 percent, the page count increases to 200 pages
When I zoom out the screen to 50 percent the page count decreases to 50 pages

In this scenario how can a user bookmark the page, because the content always flows in the book. If I bookmark page-2, and I zoom in the page-2 content will be scattered to 3 and 4 pages. I am not sure how a user can bookmark pages. Hope the answer works across all the zoom in-out 
percentages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a highlight text function then once the user highlights the text they have the option to bookmark the text.

That way regardless of how zoomed in/out they are, they are still able to get back to the right spot and continue reading merrily.

The blogging webpage Medium does this in quite a nice way:

[image]

Comment: @Pri I would suggest testing this method. Especially for the discoverability of such a feature and if it is intuitive for the user to do it this way.

Comment: Yeah, we have this feature already that we term as Annotations. I believe Reflow book user uses mostly Annotation feature, rather than bookmark

Answer (score 18):

[Rob E's excellent answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/116551/57088) covers the case where the application can (and the user wants to) mark specific passages of text.

If you also have (or want to offer) a simple "bookmark this page" option, without the user needing to mark a specific passage, then I think you should store the "location" of the paragraph at the **top** of the current page. When returning to the bookmark, display the stored location at the top of the new page.

---

My first instinct was to suggest storing the location that's closest to the *middle* of the current page (with the reasoning that if you put *that bit of text* in the middle of the page when you return to a bookmark you would be "reasonably close" to where the reader wanted to be, most of the time, for most zoom levels).

However, as an avid Kindle user, I thought about when I use the bookmark function as opposed to highlighting a passage of text:

- If a work of fiction has a map of the area where the action takes place, I'll often bookmark that page so I can return to it easily if I need to check the geography.
- If there is some kind of glossary, list of characters, ... list of *almost anything*, I again might bookmark the *first page* of such a list so I can return to it easily.

The common thing is that the thing I'm marking is usually either the only thing on the page (very often the case with maps) and/or forcibly starts a new page (usually the case with glossary or similar). In both cases, going back to the *beginning* of the page originally marked seems to be the correct thing to do.

Also, as [Monty Harder](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/79412/monty-harder) pointed out in a comment, when using a bookmark for its "traditional" purpose – going back to where you left off reading – then bringing the text that *used* to be at the top of the page *back* to the top of the page (even if the zoom-level is different) is the safest option: at worst, you might have to skim over some parts you've already read. However, if you brought what was in the *middle* of the page back to the middle, there is a chance (if the zoom-level has increased) that unread portions of the text have been pushed back on to the preceding page.

Comment: This has the advantage that if I'm returned to the top of the page where I left off reading, I can quickly locate the exact spot where I left off, but if you try to bring up what was at the middle last time, I might miss a few lines that flowed onto the previous page.

Comment: This is also a good work around.

Answer (score 1):

When bookmarking my place in a physical book, unless it's a chapter boundary or similar, I always place the bottom of the bookmark on the specific line where I want to resume. Bookmarking ebooks, whether reflowable or not, should work the same way - you don't bookmark a page but a specific point in the text.

Comment: "_Bookmarking ebooks, [...] should work the same way_"  The "problem" is that with all eBook interfaces I've seen, you _either_ bookmark a (whole) page, _or_ highlight a portion of text. You _could_ add a paragraph/line/character-level bookmark function – but then you'd have three ways of marking, which could be cumbersome; you could _change_ the bookmark function to operate at para/line/char level, but that would require extra "fiddling" if you only want to mark the page. While not perfect, I think I'd stick with bookmark page; highlight/annotate specific position.

Answer (score 1):

The Document Object Model (DOM) structure of the document might be useful here:  While the display reflows, the underlying markup of the EPUB ought to remain the same, so a bookmark could be a reference to a node in the document.

The brute-force way to do this would be to give every paragraph, for example, a unique ID based on chapter and paragraph number.  Alternatively, you might find it better to store a bookmark based on the DOM alone - that's what a computer recognises.